# Input date placeholder value in iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

I have an input tag with the date type for my mobile website, but the placeholder value is not  visible when I open it with my iPhone.

```
 <input name="birthDate" class="input-textbox" type="date" placeholder="Birth Date">
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because "Birth Date" is not a valid "date" value (you do have this field typed as "date" after all).

Comment: i know it is, i just want it to have a title. Also when i open it on my computer it displays month/day/year however it is empty in my phone(actually the main part i was trying to ask was this). what should i do for it to display a value before the user interaction?

Answer (score 1):

[Date type doesn't support placeholder.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#input-type-attr-summary)